# Magento 2 stripe module upgrade deployment on Production environment throw in Stripe error

Tags: magento2

I am deploying my new stripe module upgrade changes in a Magento production environment. In the development environment, it is deployed successfully and running well. But in a production environment when I deploy it, it throws this error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: initStripe is not defined
```

[image]

After deployment by git pull i run all the required magento commands but it does not work

```
php bin/magento s:up && php bin/magento s:d:c && php bin/magento s:s:d -f
```

Answer (score 0):

That was cloud flare cache issue.
Page JS file are loaded from  cloud flare  cache, once cloud flare cache refreshed, the problem solved.